# How to use code snippets into Aptana 3 Studio?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, aptana

I am using Aptana 3 Studio to develop PHP\HTML webapp and I have the following problem:

If I go in: **Window ---> Show View ---> Snippets** it appear to me the code snippets box tab.

Here I can chose a category of possibile snippets (for example **CSS** code snippets), so I can expand it and see all the CSS code snippets.

My problems are:

1) Can I modify an existing code snippet? (I am trying but seem that I can't do it)

2) Can I add a new code snippets category? (for example what can I do to add my new snippets category named **BootStrap**)

3) Can I add a new code snippet into a specific category?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

You can modify an existing snippet and create new ones. Here is a step-by-step guide (first result on Google, FYI)

http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/06/add-or-edit-code-snippets-and-templates-in-aptana-studio-3/

The author does mention just searching for the .rb files though, you can see a better explanation for how to get into them in the [updated version](http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/09/best-way-to-add-or-edit-code-snippets-and-templates-in-aptana-studio-3/) of the post he mentions. Basically you want to open a CSS file in the css editor and then use `Commands > Bundle Development > Edit this Bundle` and it will create a project for you that contains the rules for CSS files (including snippets), which you can then edit.